# Hierarchical with room in PCB Altium

Tags: pcb-design

I have a basic Altium design project of an amplifier, shown in the attached link.

My goal is to get a PCB as shown below.

I have tried to make the schematics into hierarchy and made 3 copies of the amplifier schematics.

When I try to turn it into a PCB I get a bunch of messages to delete stuff.
Please help me understand the PCB picture as shown below?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q7Kqm4tA2L8L3RTxEykqgFBaIcYa0qrp/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

[image]